Capacitor Android Studio Live Reloading
I'm developping a mobile app using Capacitor with just plain HTML, CSS and JavaScript (without Ionic or any other framework).
I use VS Code for development and run it on Android Studio with a physical android device.
Now whenever i make a change in the code:

I save in VS Code
Then npx cap copy
Then npx cap sync
Then go to android studio:
File -> Reload all from disk
Then file -> Sync project with gradle files
Then hit Run App.

This is too much time consuming if I do it for every minor change in my code. Is there any way to make it simpler like live reloading?

Are you looking for something like Live Reload?

You can use the Live Reload option of the Ionic Framework which will reload the browser or Web View when you change your app's code in your development environment.

I'm not using Ionic, it's just HTML, CSS and JavaScript

In this case, you will have to take care of it yourself.
